# restler 3 api explorer incorrect param type

Tags: restler

first thx for this simple tool!

I got the following problem. In my service class i have a function which looks like this (part):

```
/**
 * get merkmale from device id
 *
 * one could get merkmale from given serial id by passing var id
 * to this function and will get back one to n results ORDER BY ORDNUNG ASC
 * in JSON format
 *
 * @url GET /:id/merkmale
 * @param int $id contains the device id
 * @throws 400 No value given for id
 * @return json
 *
 */
function getmerkmale ($id) {....}
```

The problem is, if i call the api explorer and the phpdocs all is ok but
the @param type (int) is always shown as string value.
And if i try it by typing the required value into field it says wrong value for $id.
I can type in int or string both fails. If i call it in the browser all works.

I use Restler 3 with apiExplorer on Safari/Firefox.

Hope one could help.

Thx
Inge

EDIT:
@Lucarest I tried the actual git clones already without success

Maybe the problem is in index.html?

```
<?php
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;
require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
require_once 'database/config.php';
require_once 'database/DB.php';
require_once 'controller/Say.php';
require_once 'controller/Authors.php';
require_once 'controller/kunde/kunde.php';
require_once 'controller/device/device.php';
require_once 'controller/messprotokoll/messprotokoll.php';

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\Restler\Resources'); //this creates resources.json at API Root
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->addAPIClass('Authors');
$r->addAPIClass('kunde');
$r->addAPIClass('device');
$r->addAPIClass('messprotokoll');
//... add more api model if needed
$r->handle();
```

I have placed all the APIClasses into subfolders. I didn´t get it to work by passing
the url to AddAPIClass as second paramter so i require_once the needed classes.
Could this be the problem?

Thx for your help
Inge

Comment: Can you try the latest version on github master branch? and the explorer that comes with the examples

Comment: I also tried your complete examples without any modification. Safari and Firefox both show nor int values in Explorer :(

Answer (score 0):

When you are adding namespaced classes using `addAPIClass` make sure you escape the slashes as shown below

```
<?php
use Luracast\Restler\Restler;

require_once 'vendor/restler.php';
require_once 'database/config.php';
require_once 'database/DB.php';
require_once 'controller/Say.php';
require_once 'controller/Authors.php';
require_once 'controller/kunde/kunde.php';
require_once 'controller/device/device.php';
require_once 'controller/messprotokoll/messprotokoll.php';

$r = new Restler();
$r->addAPIClass('Luracast\\Restler\\Resources'); //note the double slash for escaping
$r->addAPIClass('Say');
$r->addAPIClass('Authors');
$r->addAPIClass('kunde');
$r->addAPIClass('device');
$r->addAPIClass('messprotokoll');
//... add more api model if needed
$r->handle();
```

If you strick to PSR-0 you will not need require_once for every class